# Firefox 17.0 doesn't load/save FORM passwords after upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

I'm using Ubuntu's Firefox (lucid-updates repository).
After upgrading to version 17.0 it doesn't load or save **form** passwords!
The problem is only with form passwords and HTTP Auth passwords are OK (loads and saves)!
What is the problem?